Is it possible to know/choose what memory addresses are allocated to Risc-V assembly program on debian linux?
I am beginner in RISC-V assembly programming and i would like to know if it is possible to decide (or at least know) what memory addresses (and how many) are allocated to a program ?
I am using Gnu assembler on a debian Linux with a 64 bit RISC-V (VisionFive2).

Addresses are assigned when a program is linked and loaded into memory. The documentation for ld should be helpful.

It is possible.  Write a linker script to tell the linker what sections to place where.  That said, you should usually just let the linker assign addresses automatically.  Do you have any particular use case in mind?

Hello, thanks for your comments. One of my use case is to create as many agents as possible starting from an address. And also to calculate how many i can create with the last address allocated to my program.

What do you mean by 'agents'?

Yes, but that's a complicated question.  What belongs to you?
There is the .text section that your (ro) program goes in; your .data section (rw); your .rodata section (again ro); your .bss section (I think rw); all clearly yours. As is the stack and what you've malloc'd from heap space.
But there are others that might be yours, or shared... And what about other (related) processes, if you are interested in them.
If you go to /proc/self then maps, smaps, and other virtual files, you'll see.
A lot of people have given up...
To answer your question, every process gets its own "address space" (a mainframe term) and is loaded into the same address (assuming they are external programs and not internal and part of your shell).  I don't know what that address is, but it is fixed...
Sorry I couldn't comment.  Not enough reputation points...
